# how to add data to table view when click on button on another page?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm doing this program in JavaFX that will take data from a database created on Microsoft access and place it on a table view. Also, I created button inside the table view (Add,Delete) when clicking on add button it will open a new FXML page. In this page there are 5 TextFiled and two button (Add and Cancel) when clicking on add button it suppose to take all the data in the TextFiled and add it to my table view. But i actually could not do that. I hope that someone here have an idea of how i can accomplish this.

FXMLDocumentController.java

[image]

```
package db;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public Statement st;
    public  TableView<ObservableList> table;
    public   ObservableList<ObservableList> data; 
    private Button btnNew = new Button("New Record");

   public void buildData(){


          data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

          try{

            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\GUI\\Library.accdb","","");
            System.out.println("connected...");
            st=con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

            //SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF BOOK

            String SQL = "SELECT * from BookDB";

            //ResultSet

            ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);

            /**********************************
             * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
             **********************************/

            for(int i=0 ; i<rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){

                //We are using non property style for making dynamic table

                final int j = i;               

                TableColumn col = new TableColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i+1));

                col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<ObservableList,String>,ObservableValue<String>>(){                   

                    public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {                                                                                             

                        return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());                       

                    }                   

                });

                table.getColumns().addAll(col);

                System.out.println("Column ["+i+"] ");

            }

            TableColumn col_action = new TableColumn<>("Action");
        col_action.setSortable(false);

        col_action.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Boolean>, 
                ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });

        col_action.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList, Boolean>, TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean> call(TableColumn<ObservableList, Boolean> p) {
                return new ButtonCell(table);
            }

        });

        table.getColumns().add(col_action);
        TableColumn col_Delete = new TableColumn<>("Delete");
        col_Delete.setSortable(false);

        col_Delete.setCellValueFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Boolean>, 
                ObservableValue<Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, Boolean> p) {
                return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
            }
        });

        col_Delete.setCellFactory(
                new Callback<TableColumn<ObservableList, Boolean>, TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean>>() {

            @Override
            public TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean> call(TableColumn<ObservableList, Boolean> p) {
                return new ButtonDelete(table);
            }

        });

        table.getColumns().add(col_Delete);
            /********************************
             * Data added to ObservableList *
             ********************************/

            while(rs.next()){

                //Iterate Row

                ObservableList<String> row = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

                for(int i=1 ; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){

                    //Iterate Column

                    row.add(rs.getString(i));

                }

                System.out.println("Row [1] added "+row );

                data.add(row);

            }

            //FINALLY ADDED TO TableView

            table.setItems(data);

          }
          catch(Exception e){

              e.printStackTrace();

              System.out.println("Error on Building Data");            

          }

      }



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        buildData();
        table.refresh();

    } 



    //Define the button cell
    private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean> {
        final Button cellButton = new Button("Add");

        ButtonCell(final TableView tblView){

            cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {


                   try {
                        Second s=new Second();
                        s.start(new Stage());


                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        //Display button if the row is not empty
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(t, empty);
            if(!empty){
                setGraphic(cellButton);
            }
        }
    }

    //Define the button cell
    private class ButtonDelete extends TableCell<ObservableList, Boolean> {
        final Button delButton = new Button("Delete");

        ButtonDelete(final TableView tblView){

            delButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
                  Stage myDialog = new Stage();
                    myDialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                    myDialog.show();
                }
            });
        }

        //Display button if the row is not empty
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(t, empty);
            if(!empty){
                setGraphic(delButton);
            }
        }
    } 


}
```

FXMLController.java

[image]

```
package db;


import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public TextField t1,t2,t3,t4,t5;
    public Statement st;

    @FXML
    public void btnADD(ActionEvent e)
    { 
    }
    @FXML
    public void btnCANCEL(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {

}
}
```

Database Structure

[image]

Comment: Off topic: why do you have an add button in each row in the table? Surely you just need one Add button?

Comment: @James_D this is the requirement of my assignment. the first add button will open the second page. The second add button will add the data from the text field to the table view.

Comment: I understand that. I meant, don't all the "Add" buttons in the table (there are six of them in the first screenshot) do *exactly* the same thing? What is the point in having six buttons that have exactly the same functionality? You would only put buttons in a table if their functionality varied from row to row in the table (e.g. your Delete buttons each delete a *different* item).

Comment: Anyway, I think your question will be much easier to answer if you first improve your code (make a `Book` class, make the table a `TableView<Book>`, instead of using raw types, etc etc). (And it looks like you have two `Application` classes in your application? You should only have one.) If you use the usual patterns it is much easier for others to read your code and help. And second, you should post the relevant code, e.g. your `Second` class, whatever that is.

Comment: Uh, why did you *delete* the code from the question?

Comment: what is the generic type of your TableView? can you post it?

Comment: @James_D sorry i was just trying to update the code

Comment: @yab i posted the code check it out

Comment: @Ghezlan the generic type of TableView is ObservableList, that is incorrect, TableView<ObservableList> doesn't make sense, it should be a POJO type. what is the structure of table BookDB in database? can you post?

Comment: @yab i posted it

Comment: @Ghezlan thank you. you don't use any ORM framework?

Comment: @yab no i did not use it

Comment: @Ghezlan
oh, i see. and your controller class of the new FXML page, can you post it? i'll do some modified for you.

Comment: @yab i posted it. It's actually empty I've been trying different things. but it's all a failure.

Comment: @ok i see it, thanks you. let's make sure one thing, the FXMLDocumentController code above, does it working correctly?

Comment: @yab yes it works

Comment: @Ghezlan
in FXMLController, t1 is BookID's TextField, t2 is BookName's TextField, t3 is Author's TextField, t4 is Publisher's TextField, t5 is Price's TextField, i guess it correct??because i don't have your fxml code.

Comment: @Ghezlan i need your others code, i mean, the code where you load the new FXML page? and in FXMLDocumentController class, there is a unknown class Second, what is the package of that Second class?

Comment: @yab can i have your email to send the whole project. Second.java its the java class in FXMLController. It's a normal java class it has nothing

Comment: @yab i emailed it to you

Comment: @Ghezlan when we press the ADD button in new FXML page, we add the new data to the table view in FXMLDocumentControllor, is it right? i mean, just add to the table view, do not need to add to BookDB?

Comment: @yab yaa that's right just to the table view. need not to add it to the BookDB

Comment: @Ghezlan ok, if only need to add to the TableView, that is easier. i'll do some code refactoring base on your code.

Comment: @Ghezlan
can you please send the Access Database Driver jar too?

Comment: ok i'll send it to your email

Comment: @yab i send it to your email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my friend, base on your code, i have made some reconstruction of your code to make it working, but the code's structure is not good, if it is mine project, i won't use this structure, LOL, just for reference.
As below.

first, we need to create a TableView's generic type class, here we create Book.java for it.

```
package db;
public class Book{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String author;
  private String publisher;
  private String price;

  public String getId(){
    return this.id;
  }
  public void setId(String id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return this.name;
  }
  public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getAuthor(){
    return this.author;
  }
  public void setAuthor(String author){
    this.author = author;
  }

  public String getPublisher(){
    return this.publisher;
  }
  public void setPublisher(String publisher){
    this.publisher = publisher;
  }

  public String getPrice(){
    return this.price;
  }
  public void setPrice(String price){
    this.price = price;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(){
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((this.id == null) ? 0 : this.id.hashCode());
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj){
    if(this == obj)
      return true;
    if(obj == null)
      return false;
    if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
      return false;
    Book other = (Book) obj;
    if(this.id == null){
      if(other.id != null)
        return false;
    }else if(!this.id.equals(other.id))
      return false;
    return true;
  }

  public void setValue(String columnName, String colData){
    if(columnName.contentEquals("BookName")){
      setName(colData);
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Author")){
      setAuthor(colData);
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Publisher")){
      setPublisher(colData);
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Price")){
      setPrice(colData);
    }else{
      //BookId
      setId(colData);
    }
  }

  public String getValue(String columnName){
    String value = "";
    if(columnName.contentEquals("BookName")){
      value = getName();
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Author")){
      value = getAuthor();
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Publisher")){
      value = getPublisher();
    }else if(columnName.contentEquals("Price")){
      value = getPrice();
    }else{
      //BookId
      value = getId();
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

then modified your FXMLDocumentController.java as below:

```
package db;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

/**
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable{

  public Statement st;
  @FXML
  public TableView<Book> table;
  //public ObservableList<ObservableList> data;
  private ObservableList<Book> bookData;
  //private Button btnNew = new Button("New Record");

  public void buildData(){
    //data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    bookData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try{
      Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
      Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\GUI\\Library.accdb", "", "");
      System.out.println("connected...");
      st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
      // SQL FOR SELECTING ALL OF BOOK
      String SQL = "SELECT * from BookDB";
      // ResultSet
      ResultSet rs = con.createStatement().executeQuery(SQL);
      /**********************************
       * TABLE COLUMN ADDED DYNAMICALLY *
       **********************************/
      for(int i = 0; i < rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
        // We are using non property style for making dynamic table
        String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i + 1);
        TableColumn<Book, String> col = new TableColumn<>(columnName);
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<Book, String>, ObservableValue<String>>(){
          public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<Book, String> param){
            Book book = param.getValue();
            String cellData = book.getValue(columnName);
            return new SimpleStringProperty(cellData);
          }
        });
        table.getColumns().add(col);
        System.out.println("Column [" + i + "] ");
      }

      TableColumn<Book, Boolean> col_action = new TableColumn<>("Action");
      col_action.setSortable(false);
      col_action.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Book, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>(){
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Book, Boolean> p){
          return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
        }
      });
      col_action.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Book, Boolean>, TableCell<Book, Boolean>>(){
        @Override
        public TableCell<Book, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Book, Boolean> p){
          return new ButtonCell(table);
        }
      });
      table.getColumns().add(col_action);

      TableColumn<Book, Boolean> col_Delete = new TableColumn<>("Delete");
      col_Delete.setSortable(false);
      col_Delete.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Book, Boolean>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>(){
        @Override
        public ObservableValue<Boolean> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Book, Boolean> p){
          return new SimpleBooleanProperty(p.getValue() != null);
        }
      });
      col_Delete.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<Book, Boolean>, TableCell<Book, Boolean>>(){
        @Override
        public TableCell<Book, Boolean> call(TableColumn<Book, Boolean> p){
          return new ButtonDelete(table);
        }
      });
      table.getColumns().add(col_Delete);

      /********************************
       * Data added to ObservableList *
       ********************************/
      while(rs.next()){
        Book book = new Book();
        // Iterate Row
        for(int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
          // Iterate Column
          String columnName = rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i);
          String columnData = rs.getString(i);
          book.setValue(columnName, columnData);
        }
        System.out.println("Row [1] added " + book.getName());
        bookData.add(book);
      }
      // FINALLY ADDED TO TableView
      table.setItems(bookData);

    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("Error on Building Data");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){
    buildData();
    table.refresh();
  }

  // Define the button cell
  private class ButtonCell extends TableCell<Book, Boolean>{
    final Button cellButton = new Button("Add");
    ButtonCell(final TableView<Book> tblView) {
      cellButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
          try{
            //Second s = new Second();
            //s.start(new Stage());
            openFXMLController();
          }catch(Exception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
        }
      });
    }
    // Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty){
      super.updateItem(t, empty);
      if(!empty){
        setGraphic(cellButton);
      }else{
        setGraphic(null);
        setText("");
      }
    }
  }

  private Stage fxmlControllerStage;
  private void openFXMLController(){
    if(fxmlControllerStage == null){
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXML.fxml"));
      try{
        Parent root = loader.load();
        fxmlControllerStage = new Stage();
        fxmlControllerStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        if(loader.getController() instanceof FXMLController){
          FXMLController fxmlController = loader.getController();
          fxmlController.setStage(fxmlControllerStage);
          fxmlController.setTable(table);
        }
      }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
    fxmlControllerStage.show();
  }

  // Define the button cell
  private class ButtonDelete extends TableCell<Book, Boolean>{
    final Button delButton = new Button("Delete");
    ButtonDelete(final TableView<Book> tblView) {
      delButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t){
          bookData.remove(getIndex());
        }
      });
    }
    // Display button if the row is not empty
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Boolean t, boolean empty){
      super.updateItem(t, empty);
      if(!empty){
        setGraphic(delButton);
      }else{
        setGraphic(null);
        setText("");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the last one is your FXMLController.java. we modified it as below:

```
package db;

import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author pc
 */
public class FXMLController implements Initializable{
  @FXML
  public TextField t1;
  @FXML
  public TextField t2;
  @FXML
  public TextField t3;
  @FXML
  public TextField t4;
  @FXML
  public TextField t5;

  public Statement st;

  @FXML
  public void btnADD(ActionEvent e){
    Book book = new Book();
    try{
      Integer.valueOf(t1.getText());
    }catch(NumberFormatException exception){
      Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
      alert.setContentText("BookID must be an integer");
      alert.showAndWait();
      return;
    }
    try{
      Double.valueOf(t5.getText());
    }catch(NumberFormatException exception){
      Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.ERROR);
      alert.setContentText("Price must be an integer");
      alert.showAndWait();
      return;
    }
    book.setId(t1.getText());
    book.setName(t2.getText());
    book.setAuthor(t3.getText());
    book.setPublisher(t4.getText());
    book.setPrice(t5.getText());

    if(table != null){
      table.getItems().add(book);
      if(stage != null){
        t1.clear();
        t2.clear();
        t3.clear();
        t4.clear();
        t5.clear();
        stage.close();
      }
    }

  }

  @FXML
  public void btnCANCEL(ActionEvent e){
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setContentText("Close Window, Are you sure?");
    alert.showAndWait();
    ButtonType result = alert.getResult();
    if(result == ButtonType.OK){
      if(stage != null){
        stage.close();
      }
    }
    //System.exit(0);
  }

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb){

  }

  private Stage stage;
  public void setStage(Stage stage){
    this.stage = stage;
  }

  private TableView<Book> table;
  public void setTable(TableView<Book> table){
    this.table = table;
  }
}
```

here we done.
[image]

we delete the Second.java, because it does nothing.

Comment: Hi, is it possible that you make a download link?

Comment: i am sorry, i don't get you? what do you mean?

Comment: is it possible that you can share a download link to this java project? Can't get it to work. What JavaSE are you using?

Comment: java7 or java8 should be ok. you can't get it to work? any error message?

Comment: Main method not found

Comment: Do you have a public class extends with Application, and a method in that public class like : public static void main(String[] args) {         launch(args);     } ?

Comment: launch(args)? that's sound interesting, haven't see that one before

Answer (score 3):

### Pass a Consumer

When you create your popup, pass it a callback method that persists the data and refreshes your table. The popup should call the consumer when its 'Add' button is clicked. Here is an example of loading the popup:

```
// This method should be called with the table's 'Add' buttons are clicked
public void addButtonClicked() {
    try{
        // Load the popup
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Popup.fxml"));
        loader.load();
        PopupController controller = loader.getController();
        Parent popup = loader.getRoot();

        // Give popup a callback method
        controller.setup(
            (value)->{data.add(value);table.refresh();}
        );

        // Display popup
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(popup));
        stage.show();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        // ToDo: Handle failed popup
    }
}
```

[image]

---

### Source

Here is a full working example with the main application plus the popup fxml and controller:

**JavaFxApplication.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXApplication20 extends Application {

    // Data for the table
    private ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Item 1","Object 2","Thing 3","Product 4"
        );

    // The table
    private TableView<String> table = new TableView<>(data);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // Content Column
        TableColumn<String,String> contentCol = new TableColumn<>("Content");
        contentCol.setCellValueFactory(p->new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper(p.getValue()));

        // Action Column
        TableColumn actionCol = new TableColumn("Action");
        actionCol.setCellFactory(param->  new TableCell<String, String>() {

                    final Button btn = new Button("Add");

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (empty) {
                            setGraphic(null);
                            setText(null);
                        } else {
                            // Make sure the column of 'Add' buttons 
                            // call the right method
                            btn.setOnAction(event->addButtonClicked());
                            setGraphic(btn);
                            setText(null);
                        }
                    }
        });

        // Display everything on the stage
        table.getColumns().addAll(contentCol,actionCol);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(table));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void addButtonClicked() {
        try{
            // Load the popup
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Popup.fxml"));
            loader.load();
            PopupController controller = loader.getController();
            Parent popup = loader.getRoot();

            // Give popup a callback method
            controller.setup(
                (value)->{data.add(value);table.refresh();}
            );

            // Display popup
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(new Scene(popup));
            stage.show();
        } catch(IOException ex) {
            // ToDo: Handle failed popup
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**Popup.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.65" fx:controller="javafxapplication20.PopupController">
    <children>
        <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="126" layoutY="90" onAction="#addButtonAction" text="Add" />
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="62.0" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" text="Hello World" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**PopupController.java**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class PopupController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    private Consumer<String> callback;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // ToDo: Initialize something
    }    

    public void setup(Consumer<String> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @FXML
    private void addButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        callback.accept(label.getText());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Open new FXML page(B) on Add click on TableView of FXML page (A)
Save data entered in new B (on Add Clicked) then refresh your table view on A when your new FXML (B) is closed.